# RESTful .net or class layer, perhaps with asynchronous calls

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, rest, asynchronous, model-view-controller

I'm coming out of scientific programming, so my skills are very rudimentary.  The goal is to create a layer -- perhaps a "model" layer -- that interfaces with the database and performs CRUD operations that eventually will be used in a web application.  However, some of the CRUD operations are very computationally complex.  For example, modifying a row in a parent table may cause thousands of rows in a child table to be recalculated.  Such operations may take seconds, or even minutes.

I'd like to develop this low layer without having to understand web GUIs, or authentication, or other complexities for now.  I'd like to put it behind an unsecured windows app of some sort for debugging and development.

- Should I create an MVC project and create a model layer for this, or should I just create a simple class library that implements some CRUD operations, sitting on top of a SQL database?
- If the MVC model is the route, can a windows app (or Universal Windows app, whatever that is) be easily married to an MVC model layer?
- What is the proper approach for CRUD operations that are time/CPU intensive?  Hanging doesn't seem so friendly, but returning with a process in flight seems dangerous and complicated.  Please be gentle in your answer.  I'm an asynchronous virgin.

Thank you so much for any help.  I've a feeling I'm not in Kansas any more.

Answer (score 1):

IMO the question have multiple conflicting statements i.e. you want a REST but without understanding web GUI, so the answer will come down to "it depends" and in order to give an answer, there are some factors which needs to be considered.

- How will this application be used?
- Module within an application vs Database Manager in itself.

> Should I create an MVC project and create a model layer for this, or should I just create a simple class library that implements some CRUD operations, sitting on top of a SQL database?

If all you are planning is a wrapper over database, then you should start with a Class Library, since ASP.NET 5 is in RC stage as on date of writing, i say go for a Nuget Package as it will allow you to target multiple framework versions at once and dependency management is handled for you.

> If the MVC model is the route, can a windows app (or Universal Windows app, whatever that is) be easily married to an MVC model layer?

The answer is again it depends how you want to map it, if you are thinking of mapping as in Inter Process Communication or implementing like a DLL call, then the answer is NO

MVC works primarily on Web Requests, if you are planning to make request like an  API call to an API endpoint, then the answer is YES, Console and Universal Apps can make web requests.

Though with ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 you can self host the apps, and can use any TCP protocol and not just primary Web Protocols like HTTP/FTP etc. it still needs a TCP request and they will be two different applications.

> What is the proper approach for CRUD operations that are time/CPU intensive? Hanging doesn't seem so friendly, but returning with a process in flight seems dangerous and complicated. Please be gentle in your answer. I'm an asynchronous virgin.

Generally low level database calls itself are not asynchronous, calls to functions performing low level database operations are asynchronous, in other words, your function will not be doing asynchronous operations, calls to your functions will be asynchronous.

> The goal is to create a layer -- perhaps a "model" layer -- that interfaces with the database and performs CRUD operations that eventually will be used in a web application.

If it will be like a background worker which accepts requests, adds them to a queue and perform database operations from queue then it can be an MVC application, if you are planning it to be hosted on cloud, you can go for a worker role in Cloud Service.

EDIT: Based on info in comments

Async is just a way of work which means that the calling thread is not waiting for the heavy task to finish by putting it on a background thread. Allow me the privilege to explain by example

Your website gets a high traffic and concurrently 5000 users are using your website, for simplicity of example, assume all requests arrive at the same time.

Your website is designed really good and the request gets finished in around 200ms, by default IIS allows 1000 worker threads so your 5000 requests gets served in 1 sec, that's a good thing.

Now assume those requests performs a heavy database operation which will take 5 seconds to complete, now if you perform these operations in a synchronous fashion, after 1000 requests, the web server will be unable to handle requests and those remaining 4000 requests will receive a **503 Service Unavailable** response, for a moment if we assume that web requests are served from a queue, the total response time will be 25 seconds

Now if we perform the operation in an asynchronous fashion the request is sent to the database and the web server thread is freed up to serve new requests and reattaches the request when response is received from the database and performs the operation. Total response time for the 5000 requests will be approx 6 seconds assuming your database can handle 5000 concurrent requests.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your response, Abhishek.  I'd like to eventually move this app to a web server.  Initially, I'd like to develop the back end without having to get too deep into understanding web protocols.  So, the first step is a high level database interface: basic CRUD plus complex operations. This will be used within a windows app initially.

Once the basic layer is complete and the windows test app is complete, I'd like to move it to a RESTful server app.  So, I was hoping to develop a basic class and then migrate it to an MVC model layer.  Async/worker seems like a problematic mapping.

Comment: @jlear Well go for a Class Library then (or a Nuget Package would be even better) to start and when you are ready, create another MVC app which uses the Library and provides a web endpoint. Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: That sounds like a great idea, thank you! The async is still a bit fuzzy and probably deserves a question by itself.  When I implement async methods, is there any concern about using this in or mapping it to MVC? Suppose some future web client initiates an update to a row which causes a very long process to get kicked off, but then immediately tries to update the row again. I assume there's some type process control/status strategies for standard async methods. Is there any special care that should be taken so they will map into the MVC space okay?

Comment: Thanks @abhisek!  I understand the basics of async, although now I see the mathematical criterea for choosing async.  But I have a lot of questions about database coherency when a client may send two back-to-back requests that might conflict.  That topic should be in another question, rather than beating this one to death (or it's probably been answered somewhere).  You've been very helpful.  Thanks again!

Comment: @jlear I agree that any more async stuff than this will go out of scope of this question, for the rest of your questions you can ping me at abhishek_siddhu@yahoo.com